# as3 Font size for drop down list inside ComboBox

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, combobox

[image]

How to reduce the font size of the drop down list in order to fit the contents.

Thanks,

Comment: Well, I found an answer for myself here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311141/combobox-text-formatting-through-as3?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title says comboBox but your write-up says dropdownList so I provided examples for both:

```
<s:DropDownList fontSize="8"/>
<s:ComboBox fontSize="8"/>
```

Edit:
Added below based on new info:

```
var dropdown:DropDownList = new DropDownList();
dropdown.setStyle("fontSize", "8");
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you provide the AS3 code for it, It's a Flash Professional Project, and it's about DropDownList, I'm editing title