# ComboBox Text Formatting through AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, combobox

I am developing an AIR application and I need to change the font size of the text that is displayed in the dropDown List as well as the main text on the comboBox. My ComboBox is quite big in size but the text displayed in it is very small. I tried using the setStyle method by passing a TextFormat into it like :

```
cmbEmployee.setStyle("textFormat", txtform);
```

but it didn't work. Although the same method works well with a TextField.

Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [`ComboBox`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ComboBox.html) is a container that contains a [`textField`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ComboBox.html#textField) and a [`dropdown`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ComboBox.html#dropdown) component. You need to apply the *"styles"* to the specific components inside of the ComboBox:

```
// Text Formats that needs to be applied on your comboBox
var txtformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
    txtformat.size = 30;   // Lets just increase the size of fonts   

// Increase the main TextField's font size of your ComboBox
yourComboBox.textField.setStyle("textFormat", txtformat);

// Increase the font size to the dropdown component
yourComboBox.dropdown.setRendererStyle("textFormat", txtformat);
```

Comment: Why not just use the `fontSize` style that the `ComboBox` defines?

Comment: Oh, to answer my own question, I guess this really isn't a Flex `ComboBox` -- even though the question seems to be tagged with "Flex" :) . The Flex `ComboBox` doesn't have properties named `textField` or `dropdown` like the `fl.controls.ComboBox` does :)

Comment: @Sunil D. that fontSize style didn't work for me.. I almost lost a day over it.. I am working on Flash CS5

Comment: Oh! my bad.. removed the flex tag now.. i was just so eager to get an answer from all the actionscript experts :)

Comment: @Sonyhan my bad too, I immediately assumed that the Flash CS5 and Flex combo box components would have the same API's!