# change font size of dropdown combobox flex/flash

Tags: css, apache-flex, fonts

I am looking for a solution to increase font size in dropdown combobox by Flex/flash.  I have globally replaced several small font size to larger ones ( 6pt => 9pt, 8pt=> 11pt) in Style.css.  But no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [as3 Font size for drop down list inside ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883628/as3-font-size-for-drop-down-list-inside-combobox)

Comment: Well, I found an answer for myself here. And it works!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311141/combobox-text-formatting-through-as3?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

in Style.css

```
s|DropDownList
{
    fontSize: 6;
}
```